# `rake jasmine:ci` works on c9, but running rake jasmine falls foul of port and IP issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jasmine, rake, cloud9-ide

`rake jasmine:ci` works on c9, but running `rake jasmine` does not appear to work (nothing visible on the end point), even with configuration adjusted like so:

```
Jasmine.configure do |config|
  config.server_port = ENV['PORT']
  config.host = "http://#{ENV['IP']}"
end
```

( I also tried config.host = ENV['IP'])

c9 no longer complains we are on wrong port and IP with the configuration updated, however there is no app running at the c9 endpoint and the output from rake jasmine does appear correct:

```
tansaku@saasbook-ruby:~/workspace/myrottenpotatoes (master) $ rake jasmine
your server is running here: http://localhost:8080/
your tests are here:         /home/ubuntu/workspace/myrottenpotatoes/spec/javascripts
your source files are here:  /home/ubuntu/workspace/myrottenpotatoes

[2015-08-10 02:41:06] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-08-10 02:41:06] INFO  ruby 2.2.1 (2015-02-26) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-08-10 02:41:06] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=7713 port=8080
```

(I get "No application seems to be running here!")  Conversely a rails app in the same instance works fine ...

I'm wondering if there is something that jasmine does in terms of presenting the endpoint that prevents the c9 endpoint working; although I can't immediately see why it wouldn't since c9 is set up to serve both rails and ruby apps ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah, found the solution.  We need to set rack options in jasmine.yml instead:

```
rack_options:
  Host: '0.0.0.0'
```

Now it works

Answer (score 1):

Your server should be running at 0.0.0.0:8080 to be accessible externally. I'm not sure why overriding config.host with ENV["IP"] still gives you 'http://localhost' since running `echo $IP` on your terminal should give the result `0.0.0.0` instead on a hosted Cloud9 workspace. Please try again with `config.host = "http://0.0.0.0"` or `config.host = "0.0.0.0"` just to be sure.

Comment: hi @Mutahhir - indeed - config.host = "http://0.0.0.0" or config.host = "0.0.0.0" both give exactly the same result all round - from the rake jasmine output to the lack of application on the endpoint.  I believe 0.0.0.0 is interpreted as localhost by some systems.  Perhaps this is a rake jasmine bug in that the config.host setting is being ignored ... it's not documented - I just inferred it from the source code ...

Comment: yeah, I looked at the source too. It should work since its `attr_accessor` but for some reason port has an explicit setter while host doesn't. Not sure what that means. In any case, unless you're able to listed on 0.0.0.0:8080, you won't be able to access it externally :(

Comment: yeah, I'm starting to get the sense that the server is not referring to the host variable: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-gem/blob/2cd7c64999924e0b8525e5af0d05629a54837332/lib/jasmine/server.rb#L2